# Signing in Visual Studio 2005 - error using existing .pfx

Tags: visual-studio-2005, signing, pfx

1. Built my project.
2. Created my .pfx using sn.exe -k (to create ShellTradingCCMPROD.pfx).
3. Copied the file to the application folder.
4. In VS 2005, I go to the Signing tab, 'Select From File' and browse to the .pfx file.
5. I hit 'Open' and I get the following error:

The file 'C:\2009.02.1.1\ShellTrading.CCM.WinUI\ShellTradingCCMPROD.pfx' could not be imported: Cannot find the requested object.

Other .pfx files work - any clues?

Comment: What happens in VS2008 (or VS2010?)

Answer (score 0):

`sn.exe -k` does not create a file in the .pfx format. I don't have VS2005 around anymore, but it works in VS2010 when I name the file `ShellTradingCCMPROD.snk`. The key in this file is not password protected.

As far as I know, you cannot use sn.exe to create password protected keys.

Answer (score 0):

U can refer to the below link as it explains very carefully how to solve this particular problem.

```
http://odondo.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/signing-assemblies-with-a-pfx-file/
```